# Mathematic way to know 50 km around an specific coordinate

Tags: math, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I'm investigating about the best way to know what coordinates are around an specific coordinate.
I mean:
If am in the coordinate:

```
@29.817178,-95.4012915
```

How I can know if the coordinate: @30.00121, -93.13213 has 50km (or less) of my actual position?

Comment: You need to mention that items lie on a spherical surface only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with latitude and longitude, you need to calculate the [great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) between your two points.

The formula is a bit detailed so I won't reproduce it here, but it's explained in the above linked Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), a good explanation can be found [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) with a javascript example.

Comment: Hey! that is really usable 
`var R = 6371; // km
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;`
Thanks!